# How do I merge two time series with different time values in python?

Tags: python, merge, sequence

I have:

```
highhz =  [(0,1),(2,2),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)]
lowhz=    [(1.5,1.5),(5.6,5.6)]
```

And I'd like:

```
alldata =  [(0,1,1.5),
            (2,2,NaN),
            (4,4,NaN),
            (5,5,5.6),
            (6,6,NaN),
            (7,7,NaN),
            (8,8,NaN)]
```

That is to say, attaching values from the second, low-frequency source to the ordinate values in the high-frequency source to make a combined table with the time ordinates of the high source and NaNs where there's no low-frequency data.

Any ideas how to go about this in python? In C I'd use two moving pointers, and in lisp I'd recurse, but even if I can bodge those algorithms into python, they don't look idiomatic.

Comment: please explain on what condition do you want to align data

Comment: let's say, if (a<b<c) then b goes with a.

Comment: what is `b` then? (You have two values in every element of lowhz) and you won't find anything that fits in `2 < x < 2`...

Comment: oh, sorry, that's confusing. It's supposed to be (time, value1, value2) and (time, value3), and the merge is on the time values and the data values get preserved

Comment: (1.5,a) goes between (0,b) and (2,c), and so a gets associated with 0 and the result is (0,b,a), (2,c,NaN)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from bisect import bisect_left
from pprint import pprint

dct = OrderedDict()
for t, v in highhz:
    dct.setdefault(t, []).append(v)
times = list(dct)

for t, v in lowhz:
    ind = bisect_left(times, t) - 1
    dct[times[ind]].append(v)
#----        
for k, v in dct.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        v.append(float('nan'))
#----
print [[k] + v for k, v in dct.items()]
#[[0, 1, 1.5], [2, 2, nan], [4, 4, nan], [5, 5, 5.6], [6, 6, nan], [7, 7, nan], [8, 8, nan]]
```

A slightly modified version of the above code that will insert uniform amount of `NaN`s in case the number of items that fall between two times are more than 1:

```
highhz = [(0, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8)]
lowhz = [(1.5, 1.5), (2, 2), (5.6, 5.6), (5.7, 10), (5.8, 20)]
#----
max_n = len(max(dct.values(), key=len))

for k, v in dct.items():
    le = len(v)
    v.extend([float('nan')]*(max_n-le))
#----
pprint([[k] + v for k, v in dct.items()])

[[0, 1, 1.5, 2, nan],
 [3, 3, nan, nan, nan],
 [4, 4, nan, nan, nan],
 [5, 5, 5.6, 10, 20],
 [6, 6, nan, nan, nan],
 [7, 7, nan, nan, nan],
 [8, 8, nan, nan, nan]]
```

Comment: Gosh, that's really very clever! I'm a bit worried about the extra log(n) that comes from the fact that it works even if the two series aren't sorted to start with, but it certainly solves the problem. (modulo the bug when ind is -1, which is easily fixed)

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden I wasn't sure what you wanted to do for index = 0 scenario, so left is as is. In my opinion data structures provided by [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) are much more suitable for you problem, you should check it out.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it contains the vital clue to use bisect to insert the low frequency data. I think I can knock something up with that that's both idiomatic and faster than the obvious iteration/recursion. Thanks ever so!

Answer (score 0):

Does it solve your problem?

```
highhz =  [(0,1),(2,2),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)]
lowhz=    [(1.5,1.5),(5.6,5.6)]

# hash lowhz tuples with floor from the first value
low_d = {int(x) : x for x, _ in lowhz} 
# {1: 1.5 5: 5.6}


# use fact, that dict.get() takes default value as optional argument 
result = [(x, y, low_d.get(y, None)) for x, y in highhz]
# or as @Ashwini Chaudhary suggested:
result = [(x, y, low_d.get(y, float('nan'))) for x, y in highhz]
# [(0, 1, (1.5, 1.5)),
#  (2, 2, None),
#  (4, 4, None),
#  (5, 5, (5.6, 5.6)),
#  (6, 6, None),
#  (7, 7, None),
#  (8, 8, None)]
```

Comment: passes test cases with 100% ratio, please fill another bug ;) But seriuosly, that's why I +1'd your answer. Didn't even know `bisect`, thanks.

Comment: Try with: `highhz = [(0, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8)]; lowhz = [(2, 1.5), (5.6, 5.6)]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list compare but it generate an extra `(0, 1, 'Nan')` i dont know why ??? :)

```
>>> [i+(max(j),) if max(i)<max(j)<max(i)+1 else i+('Nan',) for i in highhz for j in lowhz]
[(0, 1, 1.5), (0, 1, 'Nan'), (2, 2, 'Nan'), (2, 2, 'Nan'), (4, 4, 'Nan'), (4, 4, 'Nan'), (5, 5, 'Nan'), (5, 5, 5.6), (6, 6, 'Nan'), (6, 6, 'Nan'), (7, 7, 'Nan'), (7, 7, 'Nan'), (8, 8, 'Nan'), (8, 8, 'Nan')]
```

Comment: The extra tuples is due to the fact that you're iterating over lowhz(twice) for each item in `highhz`. Using a normal-loop with `break ` might help.

Comment: i think so ! but do you know any way that can do this with list comprehension ?